# Laptop overheating and battery drain after installing Ubuntu 23.04 (Dual boot)

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, hybrid-graphics

I have installed ubuntu 23.04 (my first linux os) along with my windows (dual boot) on my Laptop and now it's heating up like crazy and my battery is draining. I know that this is caused by 2 graphics cards that I have one is intel's irix and other is dedicated graphics card which is NVDIA.

I want a solution for this heating and battery draining problem. I know this is because drivers optimization problem and all. I have checked online where some have recommended to turn off one graphics card and have given some commands. But I dont know how that will work so PLEASE help me how to solve this issue.

My Laptop:
Processor: Intel i5 11th gen,
RAM: 20GB (4GB + 16GB-Manually Added)
ROM: 256GB-SSD  and 1TB-Hard disk
Graphics Cards: Intel Irix and NVDIA (mx 330)
[image]

Comment: In any case you're very much mistaken in your assessment. The problem, if any. is NOT having 2 graphics cards, a quite common hardware configuration, the problem is likely due to working always with the dGPU (Nvidia) when you don't need to. Unlike what happens in Windows where the Nvidia driver toggles seamlessly, in Linux most of the time the "on demand" profile has issues and/or is unavailable or not the default. Open Nvidia X Server Settings, change the profile to the iGPU (Intel) and reboot. Test and [edit] your question to update it with the results. Thank you.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have read that that people who have 2 graphics card in there machine are having this problem that's why i said that. I checked the Nvidia X Server Settings and i noticed that "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" is unavailable and Nvidia On-Demand is available. I have attached screen shot of the App please check 
I just want to my laptop to use intel graphics card for display and NVDIA for programs like which include tensorflow. And my laptop do not ovreheat.  
Thank you.

Comment: If the profile you want isn't available it means the Intel Graphics is probably too new and not yet correctly supported in your Ubuntu release (Intel Graphics drivers are open source therefore already included in the kernel) so I'll provide a tentative, WIP ("Work-In-Progress") answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing/re-installing the needed Intel Iris XE Graphics support:

```
sudo apt install mesa-va-drivers intel-media-va-driver intel-microcode
```

Reboot.

Again, open Nvidia X Server Settings and now the "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" should be available. Select it and reboot.

Comment: It say's "Unable to locate package mesa"

Comment: Please check the revised answer. Also make sure you have all the default repositories enabled and, of, course yous system fully updated.

Comment: It say's its already installed. And even after i reboot after that it does not enable the Intel option

Comment: Maybe it needs an UEFI update.

Comment: Thank You for your assistance. 
I actually found a solution. I have to run the command  **sudo prime-select intel** to work with intel graphics card. Unfortunately, the option in Nvidia server settings app the option for intel still stays grayed out but it shows its selected at least. We can turn on nvidia mode from there but not to intel. It looks like nvidia dont want us to use intel.